# How can I efficiently compute the sum of parts of an array of sizes in an arithmetic sequence?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to find the sum of parts of a given array with a length that is the sum of the first `N` positive integers for some whole number `N`. The size of each part for which I am to find the sum are the numbers in said arithmetic sequence. For instance, for an array of length `10`, I need to find the sum of the first number, the next two numbers, and so on, until the next `N` numbers.

**Example Input:**

```
[1,4,5,2,6,7,9,8,7,10]
```

**Example Output:**

```
[1,9,15,34]//1, 4+5, 2+6+7, 9+8+7+10
```

**Explanation:**

The first sum is `1`, the first element (index 0). The sum of the next two numbers is `4 + 5 = 9` (index 1 and 2). The sum of the next three numbers is `2 + 6 + 7 = 15` (index 3, 4, and 5). The sum of the last four numbers is `9 + 8 + 7 + 10 = 34` (index 6, 7, 8, 9).

Comment: Is this a problem from some competitive programming site? If so, would you mind providing the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compute the size of the result array using the formula for the sum of an arithmetic sequence, i.e. `n(n + 1) / 2`.

A prefix sum array can be applied here so so that any range sum can be computed in `O(1)` time with `O(n)` precomputation time and space (which is also the overall complexity of this algorithm).

```
final int[] input = { 1, 4, 5, 2, 6, 7, 9, 8, 7, 10 };
// size * (size + 1) / 2 = input.length
final int size = (-1 + (int) Math.sqrt(1 + 8 * input.length)) / 2;
// derived by quadratic formula
final int[] result = new int[size];
final int[] sum = new int[input.length + 1];
for (int i = 1; i <= input.length; i++) {
    sum[i] = sum[i - 1] + input[i - 1];
}
for (int i = 1, j = 0; i <= input.length; i += ++j) {
    result[j] = sum[i + j] - sum[i - 1];
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

[<kbd>Ideone Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/iZ3egy)

Comment: Is there another way not using n(n + 1) / 2 formula? What is the time and space complexity for your solution?

Comment: @ehsanhosseini It is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

The following algorithm is very efficient and does not rely on the summation formula to work (as you had asked about) other than to compute the length of the result array.  This should not be a problem since it is basic algebra.  If you use a `List` implementation you would not have to do that.

It also only sums only to the max allowed by the given array.  So if you provide an array like

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
```

It will silently ignore `11` `12` and `13` since they don't comprise enough values to continue.

Here is the algorithm with your original data set and the output.

```
        
int[] arr = { 1, 4, 5, 2, 6, 7, 9, 8, 7, 10 };

int start = 0; // start of group
int end = 0; // end of group
int[] sol = new int[(int)(-.5 + Math.sqrt(2*arr.length + .25))];
for (int i = 1; i <= sol.length; i++) {
    // initialize the sum
    int sum = 0;
    // compute next end
    end += i;
    // and sum from start to end
    for (int k = start; k < end; k++) {
        sum += arr[k];
    }
    // old end becomes next start
    start = end;

    sol[i-1] = sum;
}
```

Prints

```
[1, 9, 15, 34]
```

Comment: Well, why don't you run a comparative test and see for yourself.   I don't have JMH installed but would really like to know for certain.  BTW you throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception unless the source array is of size `(n)(n+1)/2` some positive value of n .

Comment: Ok. I did my test.  Very basic. `200` arrays each of array size of `(1000)*(2001)`, randomly generated.  My method ran in `0.871026828 seconds` yours in `2.043030972 seconds`   All results were saved and compared equal.  The order of the tests were reversed with similar numbers.  I still welcome someone to do a JMH test.

Comment: I would like to see those tests, but have you tried for array sizes larger than `1e5`?

Comment: I said the array size was 2001000.  BTW, both you and I each take the exact same number of iterations to do the calculations. 2003000.

Comment: Sorry, I must not have read your code properly. I would still be interested in seeing some tests, though.